# Scheduling parametric Crystal Report on SAP BI platform through .NET SDK?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, business-objects

I need to programmatically schedule / generate a Crystal Report, served through the BI platform, with parameters, and set data source credentials.

**To provide some history**

I have attempted to do this using the Business Intelligence Platform RESTful Web Service endpoints (as per code snippet below, following the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/220244879d104f2e8e8b37e0fa0bdd2d/4.2.3/en-US/sbo42sp3_bip_rest_ws_en.pdf)), but it seems scheduling with parameters and data source credentials is not supported (confirmed [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/450175/how-can-i-get-the-parameter-template-for-cre-repor.html)).

```
POST http://IS-CRYSTAL-DEV.coronation.com:8080/biprws/infostore/5751/scheduleForms/now
```

One can schedule through the /raylight REST API, but that only works only for WebI reports, not classic Crystal Reports, as confirmed [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12740801/crystal-report-template-visible-in-infostore-but-n.html).

Because I cannot schedule / generate a Crystal Report with parameters, and set data source credentials. using RESTful Web Service endpoints, I am attempting to use the .NET SDK to do this.

**My problem**

I am using the [SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio .NET SDK Developer Guide](https://help.sap.com/doc/305e804dfee640ac9aadeb4ac352f05c/SP21/en-US/crnet13_sp21_dg_en.pdf), specifically referring to section *1.4.5.3.1.6 Binding to ReportSource (SAP Crystal Reports Server or SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise 11)*.

The following assembly references are required to be added to the project:

- CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework
- CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore
- CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource
- CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers

However, the *CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework* and *CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore* were not installed during installation of SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (SP29) installation package for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE from this link: https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-crystal-reports-visual-studio-trial.html.

Therefore, I cannot logon to SAP Crystal Server / BI Platform, let alone access a report through InfoObject to do the scheduling I require.

**Extra info**

- I am part of a company which uses Microsoft C#.Net, hence I'd prefer
  not to use the Java SDK
- Crystal Reports 2020 Patch 2, Version 14.3.0.3625
- SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.3, Version : 14.3.0.3625.2

**My Questions**

1. Am I correct in saying that one cannot schedule a Crystal Report with parameters and data source credentials through the Business Intelligence Platform RESTful Web Service endpoints? If one can, then how (the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/220244879d104f2e8e8b37e0fa0bdd2d/4.2.3/en-US/sbo42sp3_bip_rest_ws_en.pdf) does not specify)
2. Is it possible to programmatically schedule a Crystal Report (served on the BI Platform) with parameters, and set data source credentials, using the .NET SDK?

2.1. If so, where can I get the CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework and CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore DLLs?

2.1.1. If those details are not required, then how do I schedule a report
with the .NET SDK?

2.2. If not, is there any way to programmatically schedule a schedule a Crystal Report (served on the BI Platform) with parameters, and set data source credentials; other than using the Java SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports .NET SDK does not support connecting to BOE any more. Instead, one needs to use the BOE .NET packages, accessible [here](https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-bi-edge-edition.html)

The answer is on the [SAP Community Forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13173741/how-to-use-net-sdk-to-schedule-report-served-out-o.html)

Comment: @JasonCollier thanks for listening :) Also you can use [text](hyperlink) to format links as inline links :) like this `[google](https://google.com)` gives -> [google](https://google.com)